# Linux Clementine show part of file path

Tags: linux, id3

Clementine music player has an option to show genres, but the genres supported by id3tag don't exactly fulfill my needs. However, my music is sorted like so.

```
`/home/me/Music/GENRE`
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to display the filepath bar but just show the GENRE part.